# How to publish (serve) allure report at Github Actions

Tags: testing, automation, reporting, allure, test-reporting

I run automation test cases at Github Actions, for reporting purpose I use Allure. As a result of `./gradlew allureReport` command I'm getting files at ./build/reports/allure-report directory and the main problem for me that Github Actions cant `serve` this test results.

It's justly possible to download files generated to `./build/reports/allure-report` directory, but I need for my test report to be interactive and reachable by link (examle: https://allure-framework.github.io/allure-demo/5/). Maybe somebody is aware of best practice how to serve Allure Report at Github Actions?